# Kentico10 Cultures not independent

Tags: content-management-system, multilingual, kentico, culture

I have a kentico10 website set up but the different languages are linked somehow. So if i make changes on the spanish version of the site the others change as well. Any ideas as too what this could be?

[image]

Comment: Brendon, one of the key takeaways here is that - in Kentico - the *Design* tab does not really belong to the Page, it belongs to the page template.  In your example above, you're not changing the Spanish version, you're changing the shared template.  As a rule, I try to avoid making changes in the design tab to reinforce this and focus my editorial changes in the Page tab and the Form tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've hard coded your text/code in your template layout then you will need to use localization resource string to get the correct value OR update your template to be more dynamic by using different webparts and zones.  I'd suggest NOT using different templates for every language, it becomes a management nightmare.  Make your templates dynamic enough to allow for different content to be placed for different languages.

In your example it looks like the footer text is not in English and it should be.  This is a perfect example.  In that place on the template layout add a webpart layout and then on the design view, place a editable text webpart on it.  Then when you change between languages, you can edit the text based on each individual language.  The other alternative I mentioned was to use a [localization resource string](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/multilingual-websites/setting-up-a-multilingual-user-interface/working-with-resource-strings).  These

Answer (score 0):

You can set up it the way you want. Go to properties\template - and choose a different template for you language version. Read 
[Developing unique page templates for specific languages](https://docs.kentico.com/k81/multilingual-websites/developing-unique-page-templates-for-specific-languages)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because Kentico provides a mechanism for translations of documents on multilingual sites, but not for translating entire page templates.

You can use the same template for every language, by using localized resource strings for any text you enter in the templates. (under Localization > Resource strings).

[Kentico 10 Localized resource strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaBbj.png)

You can then use the resource string's key in a macro to show the resource string for the current language. Based on the above screenshot
{$ObjectType.CompanyXYZ_Doctor$} would render as "Doctor" if the current language is English, and "Docteur" if the current language is French.

Comment: Kentico does provide methods to translate template code.  See the documentation https://docs.kentico.com/k10/multilingual-websites/setting-up-a-multilingual-user-interface/working-with-resource-strings  The problem is the OP has hard coded text in the template.  The OP needs to update his template to make it more dynamic and follow the standards for developing a localized site in Kentico.